# How can you write a Möbius transformation that maps the outside of a circle to the inside of the cirle?

Tags: circles, mobius-transformation

I am supposed to map the outside of the unit disk in the first quadrant onto the unit disk. I don't understand how you map the outside of a disc ( or part disc) to the inside.

Comment: As a hint, the Möbius transformation $\frac{1}{z}$ swaps the inside and the outside of the unit circle.

Comment: Do you want to map the outside of the unit disk in the first quadrant to the _whole_ of the unit disk? Or just the first quadrant of the unit disk? I think you must mean the first quadrant of the unit disk.

Comment: The body of the question doesn't match the title. Can you clarify? Are you looking for "a Mobius map mapping the outside of a circle to the inside" or are you looking for "a mapping (conformal??) mapping [the outside of the unit disk in the first quadrant] onto [the unit disk]"? The answers seem to assume the former, but that's not how I read the question.

Comment: If it is the latter then I suggest you try (i) first $z\mapsto z^2$ followed by (ii) $z\mapsto z+\frac{1}{z}$ and that will get you onto the upper half plane, whence it's easy to get to the unit disk.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: "the answers seem to assume the former": not so. My answer assumes that the _intended_ question was to find a Möbius transformation that maps the outside of the unit disk in the first quadrant to the inside of the unit disk in the first quadrant. (But without clarification from the OP, we are shooting in the dark here.)

Comment: Downvoted because the OP hasn't responded to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

A Möbius transformation takes the form
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
where we require $ad-bc\ne 0$. So ask yourself: what is the obvious candidate for $f(\infty)$? And for $f(0)$? These two conditions force $f$ to take a very simple form, which depends only on $a/c$. And you can further tie down $f$ with the condition that $|z|=1\implies |f(z)|=1$, so $|a/c|=1$.

If $a=c=1$, you are mapping the outside of the unit disk in the *first* quadrant to the inside of the unit disk in the *fourth* quadrant. So you have to multiply by $i$ (which is also a Möbius transformation!) to get everything back into the first quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

That's "inversion in a circle":http://geometer.org/mathcircles/inversion.pdf

Given a circle or radius "R", if the distance from the center of the circle to point "p" is $r_1$ then p is "inverted" into point p' such that p and p' lie on the same line through the center of the circle at distance $r_2$ so that $r_1r_2= R^2$.  Every point outside the circle, $r_1> R$, is mapped to a point such that $r_1< R$, inside the circle.  Every point on the circle, $r_1= R$ is mapped to itself, and every point inside the circle is mapped to a point outside the circle (the center of the circle is mapped to "the point at infinity").

Comment: Don't forget the quadrant condition!